# Missing code to display data inside of the table

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Goal:
Display data, below, inside of the table

```
"Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"
"Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"
"Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"
"Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"
"Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"
```

Problem:
What code am I missing in order to display the data inside of the table?

Info:

- I'm new in JavaFX.
- I'm using netbeans

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="787.0" prefWidth="1086.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <TableView id="ttt" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn id="firstNameCol" prefWidth="124.0" text="First name" />
          <TableColumn id="lastNameCol" prefWidth="139.0" text="Last name" />
            <TableColumn id="emailCol" minWidth="7.0" prefWidth="197.0" text="Email" />
            <TableColumn id="addressCol" prefWidth="105.0" text="Address" />
            <TableColumn id="zipcodeCol" prefWidth="100.0" text="Zipcode" />
            <TableColumn id="cityCol" prefWidth="204.0" text="City" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

```
package dreamcrm;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class DreamCRM extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );    


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

```
package dreamcrm;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

```
package dreamcrm;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class Person {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    public Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Where should I start? You do not even associate a controller with the fxml. Even if you did none of the objects from the fxml is injected to the controller, since no `fx:id` attibutes are assigned. Assuming you get that to work... you do not even attempt to pass data to the nodes created from the fxml. If you got that to work your `TableColumn`s are still missing `cellValueFactory`s. BTW: there is a tutorial out there that is doing a similar, if not the same thing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm Use it!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `fx:id` instead of `id` for this. `fx:id` will still work with CSS selectors, so no worries there.

As @fabian pointed out, and that I missed, you also need to add the `fx:controller` in your fxml file so that it knows what is going to control it.

In your document controller, you will need to let it know it is getting some info from your fxml document using `@FXML`

So like this,

```
@FXML
private TableView ttt;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol,addressCol, zipCol, cityCol;
```

Here, you use your `fx:id` as the variable name.

Then, in your `initialize` function, you will need to set the `cellValueFactory`, like so.

```
@FXML
public void initialize(){
    firstNamecol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
//etc..

//Don't forget to add your list that you made to the tableview
ttt.setItems(list);
}
```

After you add the `ObservableList` you can now add and remove items and it should update accordingly.

On a related note, you need to have `SimpleStringProperty` as a returnable value, i.e.

```
public StringProperty firstNameProperty(){
    return firstName;
}
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This code "ttt.setItems(list);" is the code for every column or somehting else or is the code "list" the ObservableList?

Comment: `ttt.setItems(list)` populates the `TableColumns` with the data.

Comment: "list" is the TableCOlumns?

Comment: `list` is the `ObservableList` with your data in it. Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm for more detailed information